# Salesforce to SAP connection inside Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, salesforce, azure-logic-apps, sap-basis

I am trying to connect Salesforce to SAP inside Azure. So far I've come across three ideas to do so.

1. Generating IDOC messages in SAP using logic Apps? Is it possible, if so what configs do we need here?
2. Using FTP/SFTP
3. Using APIs/Web Services?

If you have tried to do this and you have some advice you think it might help me please, let me know. I will appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can actually use Logic Apps in this case. You can connect to Salesforce to SAP. Configuration depends on the requirements that you have.

[image]

You can even use the web Services by [Exposing SAP functionality to the cloud with Azure App Services](https://www.codit.eu/blog/expose-sap-functionality-to-the-cloud-with-azure-app-services/?country_sel=be) which will use a combination of API Apps to create a Logic App that exposes BAPI functionality to an external website.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend an Salesforce to SAP integration from scratch. This is too much effort and you need to take care of things like error handling, delta load and security. Instead I would propose to use a tool that was made for such scenarios.

In case you only need data replication, you can go with something like SAP CPI or Mulesoft. They even offer templates, that make your life easier. You should be aware that these options can be expensive in regards to their licenses/subscriptions.

Another way would be a solution like Vigience Overcast, that offers data replication as well, but also real time access to SAP from within Salesforce. Overcast goes beyond exchanging data between the two systems, but also allows you to create the user interface. They even have pre-defined, ready-to-use apps for the most common use cases.